# How to change "[" and "]" by order with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change `"["` by order to an other element like `<span>`  in `<li>`

For example

I have this :

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>Example[Fashion][Mega]</a></li> 
</ul>
```

I want to make it like this

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>Example<span class='tag-name'>Fashion</span><span class='mega-type'>Mega</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

So I want to change the first `"["` with  `<span class='tag-name'>`
and the second with `<span class='mega-type'>`
and `"]"` with `</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.replace` and use the `g` flag to replace all

```
var a = $('a').text(); 
var _new = a.replace(/\[/, "<span class='tag-name'>")  //replace 1st"["
            .replace(/\[/, "<span class='mega-type'>") //replace 2nd"["
            .replace(/\]/g, "</span>"); //repace all "]"
$('a').html(_new);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zgzeye56/3/)**

**Update:**

this one will loop the `list` by using `.each`

```
var _new;
var a;
$('ul li a').each( function() {
    a = $(this).text();
    _new = a.replace(/\[/, "<span class='tag-name'>")
            .replace(/\[/, "<span class='mega-type'>")
            .replace(/\]/g, "</span>");
    $(this).html(_new);
});
```

**[jSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zgzeye56/5/)**

Comment: Yes it work but when we add an other <li> it doesn't work 
look: http://jsfiddle.net/zgzeye56/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace` method on the string several times using `regular expressions`. Note that this method by default finds the first occurrence and replaces it by the specified second string param.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var content = $('a').text();
    var newContent = content.replace(/\[/, '<span class="tag-name">')
           .replace(/\]/, '</span>')
           .replace(/\[/, '<span class="mega-type">')
           .replace(/\]/, '</span>');
    $('a').html(newContent);
});
```

See the **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx86nL29/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really quick way to do that using `replace( regExp, repl )`

```js
$('li a').html( function(i, txt) {
    return txt.replace(/\[(Fashion)\]/g, ' <span class="tag-name">$1</span>')
    .replace(/\[(Mega)\]/g, ' <span class="mega-type">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.tag-name {
  color: red;
}

.mega-type {
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>Example[Fashion][Mega]</a></li> 
</ul>
```

And, here is how you might automate that if you have many words to replace:

```js
var words = [{word:'Fashion',class:'tag-name'},{word:'Mega',class:'mega-type'}];
$('li a').html( function( i, txt ) {
    var ntxt = txt;
    $.each( words, function( j, u ) {
        var re = new RegExp('\\[(' + u.word + ')\\]', 'g');
        ntxt = ntxt.replace( re, function(a,b) {
            return ' <span class="' + u.class + '">' + b + '</span>' 
        });
    });
    return ntxt;
});
```

```css
.tag-name {
  color: red;
  background-color: blue;
}
.mega-type {
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>Example[Fashion][Mega]</a></li> 
</ul>
```